# How to forward a request using JAX-RS?

Tags: java, http, servlets, jax-rs, forward

I want to forward a REST request to another server.

I use JAX-RS with Jersey and Tomcat. I tried it with setting the `See Other` response and adding a `Location` header, but it's not real forward.

If I use:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request, response);
```

I get:

- `java.lang.StackOverflowError`: If the url is a relative path
- `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`: Path http://website.com does not start with a `/` character (I think the forward is only legal in the same servlet context).

How can I forward a request?

Comment: You should probably be sending a redirect. `HttpServletResponse#sendRedirect(String)`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis But this HttpServletResponse#sendRedirect(String) method basically sends a 302 HTTP response code, with the URL in the LOCATION header I think. So it's almost the same as my SEE_OTHER "solution", but it's not a real forward. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this other than using the `302` redirect? When using the RequestDispatcher.forward, I get a `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.TracingLogger$1 cannot be cast to org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.TracingLogger`

Answer (score 10):

### Forward

The [`RequestDispatcher`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html) allows you to forward a request from a servlet to another resource **on the same server**. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3916286/1426227) for more details.

You can use the [JAX-RS Client API](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/client/package-summary.html) and make your resource class play as a proxy to forward a request to a remote server:

```java
@Path("/foo")
public class FooResource {

    private Client client;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        this.client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    }

    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response myMethod() {

        String entity = client.target("http://example.org")
                              .path("foo").request()
                              .post(Entity.json(null), String.class);   

        return Response.ok(entity).build();
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void destroy() {
        this.client.close();
    }
}
```

### Redirect

If a redirect suits you, you can use the [`Response`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html) API:

- [`Response.seeOther(URI)`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html#seeOther-java.net.URI-): Used in the redirect-after-POST (aka POST/redirect/GET) pattern.
- [`Response.temporaryRedirect(URI)`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html#temporaryRedirect-java.net.URI-): Used for temporary redirection.

See the example:

```java
@Path("/foo")
public class FooResource {

    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response myMethod() {

        URI uri = // Create your URI
        return Response.temporaryRedirect(uri).build();
    }
}
```

---

It may be worth it to mention that [`UriInfo`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html) can be injected in your resource classes or methods to get some useful information, such as the [base URI](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html#getBaseUri--) and the [absolute path of the request](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html#getAbsolutePath--).

```java
@Context
UriInfo uriInfo;
```

Comment: Question is about Forwarding not Redirect.