# REST API with Jersey

Tags: java, rest, api, jersey

Is there any way in Jersey to implement an API which can mock another API? I mean when a user calls API A, it will send the request to API B then get the response from API B. Any sample code or reference for that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17654066/how-to-forward-a-request-using-jax-rs