# Servlet pure forwarding issue

Tags: java, servlets, web, resources, forward

Is it possible to fully forward a request from a servlet to an external resource?

For example:

A web has a video component with `src = ip-server/servletName`

The servlet catches the GET request for that component, validates some cookie parameters and after that processes directly (forward, not redirect) an external resource present in `http://localhost/resource.mp4`

Is that possible using Java + Servlets or I must use other technologies¿?

Thanks!

Comment: Not a duplicate, the solution proposed is to manually execute a new request to the external resource and then pass back the result. I need something that acts like a proxy doing this process automatically as if the web page actually called the resource. Moreover this solution wouldnt allow you to prompt the user to enter user+password if the resource is protected (as in case of some IP-CAMERAS)

Comment: A proxy will have to 'manually execute' a new request and 'then pass back the result'.  This is the same whether the external resource is open or the server sends a challenge requiring a username & password be entered.  There's more on how to do this in another SO post here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916214/requestdispatcher-for-remote-server

Comment: Solved, I used a variation of your suggestion using Apache HttpClient. Thanks!